# Changing a normal function to template will make any positive/negative difference?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, inline

I have a wrapper function (templatized) `Outer()` and core functionality function as `Inner()`.

```
namespace N
{
  A* Inner (void *p, int value, const int ID);

  template<typename T>
  A* Outer (T *p, const int ID)  // ID is a compile time constant
  {
    return Inner (p, p->value, ID);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
A *px = Outer(new X(3), 12345);
A *py = Outer(new Y(4), 987);
```

I am managed to pass a compile-time constant as ID. So I am thinking of changing the `Outer()` prototype to,

```
template<int ID, typename T>
A* Outer (T *p)
{
  return Inner (p, p->value, ID);
}
```

Which will be used as,

```
A *pz = Outer<333>(new Z(5));
```

Wanted to know that, is there any **code/performance level impact** with the new approach ? Will there be any **impact on inlining** ?

**Edit**: ID is surely at compile time and there are several instances of `Outer()` appearing (that's why it is important to know about `inline` also).

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Although at first glance I can't see a reason why the two versions you have will exhibit significant disparities in performance.

Comment: @In silico, I don't know how to try it. These functions would appear at several places in the code. should I compare the binaries of the 2 compiled version ? What is the reason for down vote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. One way you can test it is by writing a test program that calls the functions many times and time how long it takes. But again, I can't see a reason for any performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. The function is a template and therefore must be inlined, and constant folding like this is one of the most common optimizations done when functions are inlined. This suggests that if you have a modern compiler, it will make absolutely no difference whatsoever.

Comment: +1, so better inlining means no code bloat correct ? (specifically for my case)

Comment: @iammilind: In the vast, vast, vast majority of cases, even the idea of code bloat is ridiculous- the size of a binary is extremely small in modern standards. However, when a function is inlined, it's inlined, and how many template arguments you passed to it to make that happen are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since ID is supposed to be an `int`, the template should be

```
template<int ID, typename T>
A* Outer (T *p)
...
```

Moving on, though, as far as ups and downs go, it sort of depends on your usage, but here are some sure facts:

**Performance**

There really shouldn't be any appreciable difference. Since a new function will be created for each value of `ID`, it should performs as if you had just declared your own separate function with a local `ID` constant. So the template version *might* be quicker because no copying of values occurs at the function call, but like I said, it probably won't be significant enough to be a deal-breaker.

**Usage**

The two forms are really not equivalent. Since the function definition is defined at compile-time depending on the value of `ID`, *only* compile time constants can be used (which it seems you are expecting). In the original version, a user could write

```
int i = 10;
Outer<Z>(new Z(5), i);
```

Although `i` is a variable, it is copied to `ID` as a constant value.

In the template version, they cannot write

```
int i = 10;
Outer<i, Z>(new Z(5));
```

Since the compiler generates a different function for each value of `ID`, it can't possibly create a function at compile-time when the value isn't know until runtime

So your original version is a lot more flexible, while your proposed change is very rigid. I think most people would want to use the function in the original way, where they aren't forced to used compile-time constants. So I would stick with the original unless for some reason you *really* need the `ID` value to be a compile-time constant.

**Compiled Code**

For the compiled code, your binary will be larger (assuming you use the function for at least two different values of `ID`). This is because a new function is created for each different value of ID which is used in the program. So if you expect many different values to be used, bloat in your binary could be potentially become an issue

**Inlining**

This is something I do not have a definite answer to. I am guessing that if inlining is affected, it would probably be affected by the parameter `T` rather than `ID`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `int ID` (actually it was a typo). thanks.

Comment: @iammilind Also notice the difference in usage. You wouldn't just call it with `func<int>(new class)` but you'll have to specify the class also `func<int, class>(new class)`. So it's even more rigid then you might want.

Comment: @RedX, no need to call as you mentioned. `func<int>(new Class)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do it correctly (the code has the same functionality), then the only penalty introduced is the compilation time increase, because compiling templates takes longer then compiling normal function.

You can say "I have super fast computer, and compilation takes 1/2 second", but for big projects it matters a lot.

Comment: I very much doubt that there will be a difference in compile speed.  Templates drive up compile times for two reasons: they increase the amount of code you need to put in the header (significantly), and the type deduction can be expensive, particularly in more complicated cases.  Neither is an issue here.

Comment: @James If he wants to change normal functions into template functions, then he has to implement them in headers. Type deduction for a template function is of the same complexity as the type deduction for template class, no?

Comment: @VJo He wasn't changing a normal function into a template function.  He was adding an additional parameter to an existing template.  There is no type deduction for class templates, only for function templates.  But in his case, the intent was to always specify the type explictly, so no type deduction would be needed.  (I'm generally in favor of limiting the use of templates, because of the coupling, but in this case, given that there already was a template, the coupling is there, and it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @James I know I am most likely asking a stupid question : are you sure? Look at the title of the question : "Changing a normal function to template will make any positive/negative difference ?". With such title I expected him to really change a normal function into a template function.

Comment: @VJo Interestingly, I didn't look at the title.  The change he proposed in the question itself was to add a template argument to an existing template.

Comment: @VJo: I can't understand your position. If you actually *read* the questioner's code, it will be blatantly obvious that he is adding a parameter to an existing template.

Comment: @DeadMG The code contradict the title, and my response is to the question in the title.

Comment: @DeadMG No, I answered the question in the title, which contradicts the code. After reading more times, I still think that the compilation time increases. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your compiler and how the functions are used.
In practice, if you've got optimization turned up, the only
difference I think you'll see is in the calling syntax.  But if
you have a performance problem, profile and see where it's
coming from.